# Percorrendo JSON

Tags: jquery, json, navegação

Estou com um pouco de dificuldade de realizar uma função. Queria saber se podem me ajudar?

Bom, eu preciso fazer uma navegação via click e cada nível esta armazenado em um json. 
Uma estrutura parecida com esta abaixo:

```
{  
   [  
      {  
         "id":"2",
         "atividade":"Andou",
         "children":[  
            {  
               "id":"3",
               "atividade":"Muito",
               "children":[
                    {
                        "id":"4",
                        "atividade":"Final",
                        "children":[

                        ]
                    }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "id":"5",
         "atividade":"Voltou",
         "children":[  
            {  
               "id":"6",
               "atividade":"Muito",
               "children":[  

               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Então eu fiz um for que pega os dois primeiros níveis do json, ou seja, andou e voltou e joga na tela com seu respectivo id e índice.

Oque eu não estou conseguindo fazer é ele navegar, ou seja, clica em andou e seguir pro próximo item e quando clicar no próximo ir para mais um item e assim ir fazendo. Também preciso fazer a função que fazer ele voltar, ou seja ir voltando pela json.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Obrigado!

Comment: Renan não compreendo bem a tua pergunta. Podes explicar melhor o que acontece quando há click e onde? Dá uma olhada aqui caso ajude a explicar o que está a faltar --> http://jsfiddle.net/ksejhpgw/

Comment: Mas o que você quer que "ande" na tela?

Comment: Sergio, Perfeito, é bem oque tu montou que eu estava procurando.
Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Poderia por favor postar o código?